# How to use twin oaks DDS for an iOS app to communicate a non-iOS device?

Tags: data-distribution-service

We are using Twin Oaks DDS for windows. Can anyone help me in understanding how to use twin oaks DDS for iOS app to communicate with a non-iOS device??

Thanks,

Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general there are no special requirements for using CoreDX DDS from Twin Oaks to communicate between an iOS device and a non-iOS device.  CoreDX DDS (as with most other DDS implementations) provides for platform independence.

You will need to link in the CoreDX DDS library (specific for the target hardware) into your iOS app, and use the DDS programming API to create publishers and/or subscribers as desired - just like on any other run-time platform.

The default transport mechanism of CoreDX DDS [the Real-Time Publish Subscribe (RTPS) protocol -- a combination of UDP unicast and multicast] is designed to support typical LAN environments, and will work well over WiFi.  If you intend to communicate over cellular networks, be aware that the carrier may be using NAT or Firewall configurations that conflict with the standard UDP transport.  In this case, you may consider using the TCP based transport.